# Asset error in wails appliction converted from react application

Tags: reactjs, go, vite, wails

I have made a react project with vite, and it works correctly. Now I want to make a desktop appliction from react project using wails framework of golang, I have built the application but when I run it using `wails dev` hundreds of errors appear like these two errors:

```
DEB | [ExternalAssetHandler] Loading 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/interfaces/admin/blocks/functions/editBlock.js'

DEB | [AssetHandler] Handling request '/src/interfaces/admin/blocks/functions/deleteBlock.js' (file='src/interfaces/admin
/blocks/functions/deleteBlock.js')
```

So what may be the wrong with that :( ???? should I edit my react code in some way to run with wails ??

Answer (score 1):

Those are just debug (DEB) logs, if you wanna remove them you should change the log level to something like error https://wails.io/docs/reference/runtime/log/#logsetloglevel

> watch out if using react-router-dom and use `<HashRouter basename={yourBaseName} />` instead of `<BrowserRouter />` as the wails docs suggest (also don't do hrefs and redirects without `useNavigate` or `<Navigate />` from the react-router-dom, otherwise you'll actually search for other routes and resources instead of "/", thus losing the bindings reference to `window.go`)